# draggable multiselect jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, multi-select

I want to create a multiselect with draggable option. But I couldn't wrote and found myself. My **options** have their *priority* (the order in the list). So ex. when I drag the second item to the first place then the priority of item1 will be 2 but item2 will be 1. Additionally I can select (multiple) options.

Comment: Can you give us a fiddle or some code samples?

Comment: I'm using this multiselect (http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#basic).

Comment: Actually the multiselect plugins will use their custom elements insteed of options. If you try $('.ui-multiselect-checkboxes.ui-helper-reset li').sortable() you can make it work. Be sure to run the code once the select pugin completes initiation

Comment: If you fiddle your code, I can help you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dc41kz1k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
$(function(){
    $("select").multiselect({
        open: function(){
             $("ul").sortable();
            $( "ul" ).disableSelection();
        }
    });

});
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dc41kz1k/1/

Comment: that's perfect.. this works for me. but I want to ask how to get indexes(orders of options) using java?

Comment: additionally, this code changes the position of option visually not in backend. that's why I cannot get the changed (new) sort..

Comment: I dont know java. Also I am not clear with the "Order at backend". Do you want the order of the options after the form get submitted? Also only the selected options or all the options? Can you please clarify/